# SQL Server : Select from stored table names

Tags: sql-server, powershell

How to select from a table name stored in another able.

Here is the summary of the scenario.

table 1: item (itemid, itemname )

table 2: category(catid, itemid)

table 3: catid(time, rate)

As you can see the problem here is that the name of the third table 
is store in second table. Given that I am going to use this query in
powershell, any hints on how to write this query using or not powershell is
welcome.

Note: There is no way of restructuring the design, the design is OK.

e.g

```css
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

table, td, th {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<table border="1" width="50%">
  <tr>
    <td colspan=2><b>item</b></td>
  </tr>
 <tr>
    <td>itemid</td>
    <td>itemname</td>  
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>it01</td>
    <td>itemA</td>  
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>it02</td>
    <td>itemB</td>  
  </tr>
 <tr>
    <td>it03</td>
    <td>itemC</td>  
  </tr>
</table>

<br/>

<table border="1" width="50%">
  <tr>
    <td colspan=2><b>Category</b></td>
  </tr>
 <tr>
    <td>catid</td>
    <td>itemid</td>  
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>cat01</td>
    <td>it01</td>  
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>cat02</td>
    <td>it02</td>  
  </tr>
 <tr>
    <td>cat03</td>
    <td>it03</td>  
  </tr>
</table>

<br/>

<table border="1" width="50%">
  <tr>
    <td colspan=2><b>cat01</b></td>
  </tr>
 <tr>
    <td>time</td>
    <td>rate</td>  
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>11</td>  
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>21</td>  
  </tr>

</table>

<br/>

<table border="1" width="50%">
  <tr>
    <td colspan=2><b>cat02</b></td>
  </tr>
 <tr>
    <td>time</td>
    <td>rate</td>  
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>12</td>  
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>22</td>  
  </tr>

</table>

<br/>

<table border="1" width="50%">
  <tr>
    <td colspan=2><b>cat03</b></td>
  </tr>
 <tr>
    <td>time</td>
    <td>rate</td>  
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>13</td>  
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>23</td>  
  </tr>

</table>

<br/>

<table border="1" width="50%">
  <tr>
    <td colspan=4><b>Output</b></td>
  </tr>
 <tr>
    <td>time</td>
    <td>itemA</td>
    <td>itemB</td>
    <td>itemC</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>11</td> 
    <td>12</td>
    <td>13</td>  
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>21</td> 
    <td>22</td>
    <td>23</td> 
  </tr>

</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use dynamic T-SQL for this:

```
DECLARE @TableName NVARCHAR(50)
SELECT @TableName = catid FROM category WHERE itemID = [Some Item ID here]
DECLARE @Query NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @Query = 'SELECT * FROM ' + @TableName
EXEC sp_executesql  @Query
```

For older versions of SQL Server you can change the last line to **EXEC @Query**

That should at least point you in the right direction.

Comment: thanks for your hint, it has been very helpful in helping me to solve this problem and pointing in the right direction.